# screen 1 occaionally blanks for a second

Tags: 22.04, xorg, i3-wm, 4k-monitor

On an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system with dual 4K monitors and running i3 under X, I occasionally see one of the screens go black for a second, then recover.  The affected screen is not always the same nor is it always the same video output (when I swap cables), though it *seems* to favor video output 1.  On the other hand, it's always one screen, never both at once.  This often happens several times a day.

I've reproduced this on two separate machines with this configuration (different hardware and different cpu and screen models), so I increasingly believe this is software.  On the other hand, neither .xsession-errors nor syslog display anything suspect or even reliably similar from incident to incident.

Any suggestions what to look at or what might be the culprit?

Fwiw,

```
$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 2
 0: +*HDMI-A-0 3840/600x2160/340+0+0  HDMI-A-0
 1: +HDMI-A-1 3840/600x2160/340+3840+0  HDMI-A-1
$
```